# Enqueue & Localise only on frontend

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have added wp_enqueue_script and wp_localize_script to my functions.php and they seem to be showing up everywhere - even the backend which is causing some issues. Is there any way to limit them to the frontend only, or homepage.

Also is add_action necessary? They seem to work without it

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'frontJquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/front.js', [ 'jquery' ]);
wp_localize_script( 'frontJquery', 'ajax_page', [
        'url'   => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
] );

function savedata(){
    $stripSl = stripslashes($_POST[data]);
    $dataOf = json_decode($stripSl, true);
    $dateOf = date("H:i:s d-m-Y");
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert('user_info',
    array(
        'currentDate' => $dateOf,
        'amount' => $dataOf['moneyOf'],
        'email' => $dataOf['emailOf'],
    ),
    array(
        '%s',
        '%s'
    )
);

die();
return true;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_savedata', 'savedata'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_savedata', 'savedata');
```

Comment: first 2 lines of code: do they wrapped in some other function? or called from `add_action` ?

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan I just placed it on the top of functions.php without add-action or a function, but they still seem to work. Im new to Wordpress im not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hook into [wp_enqueue_scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts), you'll be able to inject your stylesheets and JS files conditionally.

For example:

```
function wp2441_enqueue_scripts() {

    if ( is_front_page() ){ // change for is_home() if you're not using a front page
        wp_enqueue_script( 'frontJquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/front.js', array('jquery') );
        wp_localize_script( 'frontJquery', 'ajax_page', array(
            'url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        ));
    }

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp2441_enqueue_scripts' );
// This action hook tells WP to enqueue all of these files only on the front-end.
// There's a different hook to enqueue files on the back-end.
```

---

Useful references:

- [WordPress: Conditional Tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)
- [WordPress Theme Developer
  Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/)

Comment: Ohhh, so that's how add_action works. Best explanation thus far